# Failed to Measure Children for Dynamically Created QML Object

Tags: qt, qml, pyside6

Basically, I was trying to recreate IconLabel with some of my own classes in QML. However, it worked, in a limited sense:

```json
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Item {
    id: root

    property int spacing: 8
    property string direction: "left"

    property string icon: ""
    property bool is_img: false
    property int icon_size: 24
    property int font_size: 14
    property string text: ""
    property string font: "Roboto"
    property color color: "black"
    property color icon_color: "black"
    property color text_color: "black"


    Component.onCompleted: {
        var cmd = `
        import QtQuick 2.15
        import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
        import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
        `;
        var isHorizontal = direction === "left" || direction === "right";
        var alignmentCmd = `Layout.alignment: ${isHorizontal ? "Qt.AlignVCenter" : "Qt.AlignHCenter"}`;

        var iconCmd = "";
        if (icon_color === "black")
            icon_color = color;
        if (text_color === "black")
            text_color = color;

        if (root.icon !== "") {
            if (is_img) {
                iconCmd = `MImage {
                    source: "${icon}"
                    Layout.alignment: ${isHorizontal ? "Qt.AlignVCenter" : "Qt.AlignHCenter"}
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                    width: ${icon_size}
                    height: ${icon_size}
                }`;
            } else {
                iconCmd = `MIcon {
                    icon: root.icon
                    color: root.icon_color
                    ${alignmentCmd}
                    width: ${icon_size}
                    height: ${icon_size}
                }`;
            }
        }
        var textCmd = `
        Text {
            text: root.text
            font.pixelSize: root.font_size
            font.family: root.font
            color: root.text_color
            ${alignmentCmd}
        }
        `;
        var componentCmd = direction === "left" || direction === "top" ? iconCmd + textCmd : textCmd + iconCmd;
        cmd += `
        ${isHorizontal ? "RowLayout" : "ColumnLayout"} {
            spacing: ${isHorizontal ? "root.spacing" : "0"}
            ${componentCmd}
        }`;

        Qt.createQmlObject(cmd, root, "dynamicComponent");
    }
}
```

It does do everything that I want if I used it alone, like
[image: Shown a MWE]

```json
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import "components"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MIconLabel {
        icon_color: Material.color(Material.Red, Material.Shade500)
        direction: "right"
        icon: "home"
        text: "Home"
    }
    MIconLabel {
        icon_color: "black"
        icon: "menu"
        text: "Menu"
        y: 100
    }
}
```

But for some reason, it rejects to cooperate with RowLayout or anything of this nature.

[image: Failure Case]

```json
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import "components"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        MIconLabel {
            icon_color: Material.color(Material.Red, Material.Shade500)
            direction: "right"
            icon: "home"
            text: "Home"
        }
        MIconLabel {
            icon_color: "black"
            icon: "menu"
            text: "Menu"
        }
   }
}
```

Hence, I ask if there is some way that I can make the parent detect the newly created objects (like refresh or remeasure methods?). I tried to resize the window in hope of repainting the event, but nothing good happens. I also used `console.log` at the end of the initialization method to print out the dimension of the newly created object, and the dimension of the root object, and the following expression evaluates to `True`: `root.width == object.width == root.childrenRect.width` and `root.height == object.height == root.childrenRect.height`.

Just to explain some details here: `MIcon` is a wrapper of `Text` class with the `font.family` pre-declared as `Material Icons`. And `MImage` is basically an wrapper around Image with rounded corners and a placeholder, if no image is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took sometime to read your code. My reading of your code, I get the feeling it is (1) brutal use of createQmlObject() and I would recommend finding another way to do the same thing. For example, are you aware that most components have an `icon.source` property with `icon.color` ? For instance

```
ItemDelegate {
    icon.source: "..."
    icon.color: "..."
}
```

I tried to recreate your UI with:

- `ItemDelegate` to render both text and icon
- `icon.source` and `icon.color` to colorize an SVG
- `LayoutMirroring` to implement both left-to-right and right-to-left patterns
- Added `Frame` component to visually check that the dimensions of the attempt

Here's the complete working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width
        Frame {
            ItemDelegate {
                text: "Home"
                icon.source: "home-32.svg"
                icon.color: "red"
                LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
            }
        }
        Frame {
            ItemDelegate {
                text: "Menu"
                icon.source: "hamburger-32.svg"
                icon.color: "black"
            }
        }
    }
}

//home-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M11 8.5V5H6v8.5L2.5 17H5v12h8v-8h6v8h8V17h2.5L16 3.5zM26 16v12h-6v-8h-8v8H6V16H4.914L7 13.914V6h3v4.914l6-6L27.086 16z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

//hamburger-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M28 7H4V6h24zm0 9H4v1h24zm0 10H4v1h24z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADsXicrZDNbqMwFIX3PIXlPQabYGjUdDEdVVQi0nSTPSEutmrsyBiTySjvPjbNjNpE86teIXzvPR%2FiHIt%2Br40FT%2FZpFO1LJN6N6F4ra7QcLvd181WPdoi%2BNB0D3yLg617LsVevwnkVahI7y5dg3ximLJqnn9qDaXr2hg31aFn%2FmUnWNfZSCmXZwS4BrHTP4JUoWq3QoEfTMs9wz8QZQYPrfoG2WmrjScN218RrkrUwRhuhOsRUs5VstwTWjOwdfYquu%2F%2BPtmZq%2FGO0pt%2BOpmPm7%2FJtZdO%2BwN96PkWnKEqSN3cW3foXOPRSDSvIrd0vk2SaJjRlSJsuIWmaJuHXwAk2fdKHFUxBCjLiH3h3u28sB7sVXGMMSpRv8oo6f9YE5QAXVe4w4aWLS%2B7XvNzggnulxhRkKD%2BuCQWYBiSmgYlLV1Z0g2m1QDd4URcAZ6HZUJ65eSVpTGtSoLQMXx5hcnbwLKRcQaUVg7Mbb5FnxGWkSmcoJLibg1%2Fc6AelJyUoquCTLI59Cm6qhcPnHqc%2Fhn9z%2Bx3bi%2Fyy)

Comment: my problem with this approach is I am using a custom icon font, and icon button seems only happy with an image.

Comment: @Yubo thanks for your reply. It seems my answer and your question has, somewhat, diverged. I think there wasn't original information in the question to indicate it was a font instead of an image. There isn't enough information for people to recreate your situation so, I emulated. One part of my answer, the use of `Frame` to troubleshoot dimensions is probably something you can use to confirm that your components have the correct width and height. Doing that will be a starting point. If you noticed any zero width or height, it will help you identify and solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry for my muddy description. I kinda assumed that everyone assumed I am using a Material icon font.

Thanks for your answer! After putting frames around them, I realized that I just can't make the item's width and height to synchronized with the inner widget. I finally solved this problem by simply declaring implicit with/Height in the property.....

Comment: @Yubo I was just about to update my answer to mention setting implicitWidth/implicitHeight. I am glad you found it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the superclass into `Rectangle` and binding the `implicitWidth`, and `implicitHeight` of the dynamically created object, the problem is solved.

```json
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Rectangle {
    id: root

    property int spacing: 8
    property string direction: "left"

    property string icon: ""
    property bool is_img: false
    property int icon_size: 24
    property int text_size: 14
    property string text: ""
    property string font: "Roboto"
    property color color: "black"
    property color icon_color: "black"
    property color text_color: "black"

    property var impl_object: null
    implicitWidth: (impl_object) ? impl_object.implicitWidth : 24
    implicitHeight: (impl_object) ? impl_object.implicitHeight : 24


    Component.onCompleted: {
        var cmd = `
        import QtQuick 2.15
        import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
        import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
        `;
        var isHorizontal = direction === "left" || direction === "right";
        var alignmentCmd = `Layout.alignment: ${isHorizontal ? "Qt.AlignVCenter" : "Qt.AlignHCenter"}`;

        var iconCmd = "";
        if (icon_color == "#000000")
            icon_color = color;
        if (text_color == "#000000")
            text_color = color;

        if (root.icon !== "") {
            if (is_img) {
                iconCmd = `MImage {
                    source: "${icon}"
                    Layout.alignment: ${isHorizontal ? "Qt.AlignVCenter" : "Qt.AlignHCenter"}
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                    width: root.icon_size
                    height: root.icon_size
                }`;
            } else {
                iconCmd = `MIcon {
                    icon: root.icon
                    color: root.icon_color
                    ${alignmentCmd}
                    size: root.icon_size
                }`;
            }
        }
        var textCmd = `
        Text {
            text: root.text
            font.pixelSize: root.text_size
            font.family: root.font
            color: root.text_color
            ${alignmentCmd}
        }
        `;
        var componentCmd = direction === "left" || direction === "top" ? iconCmd + textCmd : textCmd + iconCmd;
        cmd += `
        ${isHorizontal ? "RowLayout" : "ColumnLayout"} {
            spacing: ${isHorizontal ? "root.spacing" : "0"}
            ${componentCmd}
        }`;

        var object = Qt.createQmlObject(cmd, root, "dynamicComponent");
        root.impl_object = object;
    }
}
```

[image]

As Stephen Quan suggested, such a brutal amount of createQmlObject is bad. Hence, an alternative solution is proposed, despite it lacks of the ability to create IconLabel in all kinds of directions.

```json
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Rectangle {
    id: root
    property color color: "black"

    property alias spacing: rowLayout.spacing
    property alias icon: icon.icon
    property alias text: text.text
    property alias text_size: text.font.pixelSize
    property alias icon_size: icon.size
    property alias font: text.font.family

    property var icon_color: null
    property var text_color: null

    implicitHeight: rowLayout.implicitHeight
    implicitWidth: rowLayout.implicitWidth

    RowLayout {
        id: rowLayout
        anchors.fill: parent

        MIcon {
            id: icon
            icon: root.icon
            size: root.icon_size
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
        }

        Text {
            id: text
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
        }
    }

    Connections {
        function onColorChanged() {
            root.icon_color = root.color
            root.text_color = root.color
        }

        function onIcon_colorChanged() {
            icon.color = root.icon_color
        }

        function onText_colorChanged() {
            text.color = root.text_color
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (root.icon_color == null) {
            root.icon_color = root.color
        }
        if (root.text_color == null) {
            root.text_color = root.color
        }
    }
}
```

[image]